# String Comparison Failing in Javascript When Values Are Equal

Tags: javascript

I have a function that takes an abbreviated month name, and returns the numeric value for it, ex May returns 5.

Or rather it should. The problem is that no matter what I try, the string comparison always fails.

```
var monthNames = [
    "JAN", "FEB", "MAR",
    "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL",
    "AUG", "SEP", "OCT",
    "NOV", "DEC"
];

function getMonthNum(val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < monthNames.length; i++) {
        if (val.toUpperCase() == monthNames[i].toUpperCase()) {
            return parseInt(i + 1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If the val being passed in is May, it will never pass the comparison of "MAY" == "MAY", fails every time.

How can I make "MAY" == "MAY"?

I've changed the code to convert both values to strings, trimmed them, removed whitespace, nothing works.

The function eventually turned into the below and IT STILL FAILS and returns 0. Somehow "MAY" never equals "MAY".

```
function getMonthNum(val) {
    var mon = val.toUpperCase().trim().toString().replace(/\s/g, ' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < monthNames.length; i++) {
        var check = monthNames[i].toUpperCase().trim().toString().replace(/\s/g, ' ');
        if (String(mon) == String(check)) {
            return parseInt(i + 1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to parseInt on `i` which is already a Number?

Comment: Also I tried your first snippet logic and called `getMonthNum('May')` and it returned `5`.  So what exactly is not working?

Comment: Same, it seems to be working fine for me. Are you sure you didn't change anything when you copied your code here? How exactly are you calling the function?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sanqf8v5/  This logic works as is.

Comment: @Taplar it's returning 0 for me. The return parseInt(i + 1); is never being hit because it is never equating to true

Comment: What browser are you using?  Because two people now have said it works.

Comment: @J.Cart, if your code is working for everyone and the below better answer is working, are you sure you are passing the value that you think you are? When you run the fiddle, you are getting 0?

Comment: Also simply plugging `'May'.toUpperCase() == 'MAY'` in your browser console will return true.  So your assertion that it returns false is not correct.

Comment: @Taplar I just tried Chrome and all the solutions here work, that's correct. Unfortunately my company hates me and made it a requirement that it also work in IE11. And nothing I've tried will make this work in IE11

Comment: Ok, I copied the exact script from jsfiddle into a `jsbin.com` snippet runner, and it still alerted `5` for me.  So that also conflicts with your claim that this does not work.  And I tested it in IE11.  https://jsbin.com/huyepikuri/1/edit

Comment: I can't test in IE11 at the moment, but I don't think you're using anything here with browser-specific behavior. Again, how are you calling the function? And maybe try adding a `console.log` to the top of the function to make sure you're actually passing in the value you think you are.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I am using a debugger to check every value as it goes, but as I mentioned the above code works in Chrome, not IE11, so there's definitely something browser specific to IE going on

Comment: @Taplar I'm the exact same code with the exact same values in both Chrome and IE11. It does not work in IE11

Comment: I just tried this jsbin https://jsbin.com/corojonile/1/edit?html,js,output in IE11 and it works (there are other on page errors but that they are related to jsbin)

Comment: I should add, if I pass the word "MAY", it works. However I'm passing in an array cell that contains the word "May", and it fails. The call looks like this getMonthNum(date1arr[1].toUpperCase().toString().trim()); And yes I'm sure the value going into the function is the word "May", but there must be something else that's being passed that I can't figure out

Comment: @J.Cart so the function is working, the problem is something with the data you are passing. Might want to show that array source in your example since that seems to be the culprit.

Comment: @imvain2 there's so much code leading up to this I wouldn't know where to start. I am however certain that the value being passed in, is the word "May". So what I need is to figure out how to absolutely, positively convert that value into the word "May" without whatever hidden junk is there. Hence the toString, trim, regex etc...

Comment: @J.Cart, for some tests in the function, you can try `alert(val.length);` to see if its 3 characters long, also you can try stripping out all NON Letters `val.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/gi, '')`

Comment: @imvain2 I WISH YOU ALL THE GOOD THINGS IN LIFE!!! val.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/gi, '') is what finally managed to strip whatever garbage was causing it to fail. Thanks to everyone who responded as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't be confident on the data coming in, you can try removing ALL non letters in your function.

```
val.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/gi, '')
```

Answer (score 3):

`MAY` I suggest using `indexOf`?

```js
var monthNames = [
    "JAN", "FEB", "MAR",
    "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL",
    "AUG", "SEP", "OCT",
    "NOV", "DEC"
];

function getMonthNum(val) {
  return monthNames.indexOf(val.toUpperCase()) + 1
}

console.log(getMonthNum("MAY")); //5
console.log(getMonthNum("maY")); //5
console.log(getMonthNum("JUN")); //6
console.log(getMonthNum("wrong")); //0
```

Comment: Still returning 0

Comment: One note is in your `getMonthNum` function you might want to convert `val` to uppercase, just in case a lower case version is being passed.

Comment: I should amend that this solution works in Chrome, but will not work in IE11.

Comment: @J.Cart that code is working for me in IE 11 at this jsbin (https://jsbin.com/howaponecu/1/edit)

Comment: I should add, if I pass the word "MAY", it works. However I'm passing in an array cell that contains the word "May", and it fails. The call looks like this getMonthNum(date1arr[1].toUpperCase().toString().trim()); And yes I'm sure the value going into the function is the word "May", but there must be something else that's being passed that I can't figure out

Comment: Then it would be interesting to exactly see what you're passing to the function, where does your data come from. What if you print date1arr[1].toUpperCase().toString().trim() in your program? Does it prints MAY or not? Please share with us all the relevant details. The function itself works perfectly, now if your way of getting the input has some issue we need to see it :)